# How does deis scheduler work?

Tags: deis

I'm looking at the documentation of [deis](http://deis.io/) and I'm not sure how the scheduler works.

Essentially I want to deploy small apps. My idea is to have different size of apps based on memory (64M, 128M, 256M and 512M).

Then I would have a cluster of small machines (1 CPU, ~3GB) and I want to deploy/undeploy any number of apps, where most of them will only have one instance.

So in this case I need a scheduler that looks at the free memory on each node and deploy the app to the node with more resources available (in this case memory based).

For example, if I have 2GB available for apps I could have the following balancing:

```
Node1: App1 (256M), App2 (256M), App3 (512M) => Total 1.5 GB
Node2: App4 (512M), App5 (128M), App6 (128M), App7 (256M), App8 (512M), App9 (256M) => Total  1.75 GB
```

Then if I need to deploy an app that will consume 512M, the scheduler should deploy the app in Node1.

So I wanted to understand if deis could be userful for this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the hood, Deis uses [fleet](https://github.com/coreos/fleet) as a scheduler. Currently fleet awards a job to whichever machine in the cluster responds first, and has no understanding of machine load. Smarter scheduling is a priority of the fleet project, and as it improves, Deis improves.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like we will need to wait for this https://github.com/coreos/fleet/pull/237

Comment: Update one year later:  Fleet has [no plans to schedule by resources](https://github.com/coreos/fleet/issues/747), so Deis has [implemented it themselves](http://docs.deis.io/en/latest/using_deis/manage-application/#limit-the-application).